# Calculate percent of goal where start is not zero

Tags: trading, calculation

How would I calculate the percent to a goal between two numbers where the starting number is not zero? for example:

purchase price = $10

target price = $80

current price = $61

What percent to $80 is the current price in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what context your goal would be used in, but there are two approaches that come to mind.

Either you just state your goal is to reach a price of $80 and you are currently at $61, which means you are `61/80 = .7625 = 76%` of the way to your goal.

Alternatively, if you want starting price factored in then, you could rephrase your goal to be increasing price by $70, in which case you'd say that so far price has increased by $51 (`61 - 10 = 51`) so `51/70 = .7285 = 73%` of the way to your goal.

Comment: Since the delta is $70, your third paragraph is the correct answer.